# How to display a gridview consisting of rows having varying number of items

Tags: android, xml

I want to display a grid view using recyclerview which displays items in the following format:
First row contains one item.
Second row contains two items.
Third row contains one item.
Fourth row contains two items.
The format repeats afterwards.
A solution will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do Like this

```
private void configureRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                // 2 is the sum of items in one row
                switch (position % 2) {
                    case 0:
                        return 2;
                    case 1:
                        return 1;
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException("internal error");
            }
        });


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it out and let you know. :)

Comment: This code doesn't show the desired output. It displays one item in each row but in different sizes.

Comment: try to understand the code. it will make grid size based on the position. It must work.